# MySQL sort data by specific data entries

Tags: mysql

I'm not too sure if the title made much sense but I will explain in more detail.

So I have a table named 'members' which has a list of ranks (Col, Maj, Cpt) under the field name 'rank'

I would like to order the data by the rank name going from highest rank (Col) to lowest rank (Rct).

I will include a screenshot of my table just in case I don't make sense.

[Table screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c846n.png)

Comment: Personally I would add a new [Ranks] table, add the 3 string values and an integer OrderValue column, setup a key relationship, JOIN in your query and order by Rank.OrderValue

Answer (score 0):

I think Alex K.'s solution is the best. You're looking for something like

`select * from members order by rank desc;`  This will return them in descending order alphabetically. If you defined a rank table like Alex suggests you could do a:

```
select t.*
from members t join rank_table rt on t.rankname = rt.rankname 
order by rt.rankvalue desc;
```

In this solution the rank_table looks like:

Col     | 2

Maj     | 1

Cap     | 0

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So I would make a new table named ranks then fill in that table with all the ranks?

Comment: It depends what you want to do. If you just want to sort them alphabetically then you can continue on with your members table. If you want to sort them by the actual value of their rank then I would create the rank table and fill it with the rank and the "value" of that rank. 

For example, Private is the first rank you can achieve. Captain is the second rank you can achieve.


This would allow you to name ranks whatever you wanted and sort them in order of value. Private has a value of 1, Captain has a value of 2.

Comment: If I was to give them a value, so I can order them the proper rank order way, how do I set it?

Comment: Adding onto that, what are the 't' and 'rt' values that you are putting into query? Should I be replacing them with something?

Comment: You'll need to do some background reading: 
https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/alias.php
https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/joins.php

Comment: After reading that, I am still confused with what I am meant to replace 'rankname' and 'rankvalue' with.

Comment: In my example I used "rankname" as the name of the column that stores Rank Names, and "rankvalue" as the name of the column that stores Rank Values. Both the "members" table and "rank_table" have a column called "rankname"